# Facebook Issue? java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ... android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, android-resources

I have a Unity game, and the logs show my users are getting the following error.

I'm a bit lost as to where I need to start hunting to track down what this error means and how to resolve it.

Not sure if this has something to do with the com.facebook.LoginActivity?

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.game.foo/com.facebook.LoginActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1018)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2105)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:857)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:280)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
at com.facebook.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:55)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
```

Comment: Any word on this? I am getting a similar error inside of com.facebook.LoginActivity